# How to end a program with an if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

So this is a function from a slot machine project I'm working on. and I'm wondering is there a way to work it so that after the if statement claiming "your credits are too low to play" the program ends. Also can I make it so the program asks for the bet again if bet>credits or bet<2 any answers appreciated.

```
slot validate( slot s)
{
    printf ("Your available credit is %f\n", credits);
    if (credits >= 2)
    {
        printf ("How many credits would you like to bet?\n");
        scanf("%f", &s.bet);
        if (s.bet> credits)
        {
            printf("you do not have enough credits for that bet\n");
            printf("your available credits are %f", credits);
        }

        if (s.bet < 2)
        {
            printf("Error! You must bet at least to credits to play!");
        }

        if (credits < 2)
        {
            printf ("your credits are too low to play!");
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: And you really think there is no way? What are your ideas thus far? What have you tried?

Comment: You can usually exit your program with `exit(code)`, where you would use a number for `code`, typically `0` to indicate success, or non-zero to indicate failure.

Comment: `if (condition) exit(-1);`

Comment: to be honest would it not be better not to end the program until the user wants to?

Answer (score 3):

The cheap answer is to call the [exit()](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/exit.html) function.

However, `exit()` does not return -- the program exits immediately. So your `validate()` function would not return to its caller. This is a problem if there are any cleanup actions your program needs to do, such as saving state (score, whatever) to a file. The better way is to return some value from `validate()` that *indicates to the caller* that the program should end. You could do this by returning an *int* and moving the `slot` return value to a function argument which the function body can set. The caller can then do any cleanup it needs to do and return control to *its* caller, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (credits < 2)
{
    printf ("your credits are too low to play!");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` if having too few credits is an error.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I always consider FAILURE as a software error rather than user error (due to having too few credits). I guess it's personal preference!

Comment: In that case, I suggest `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` for portability.